# Python - Capture Click events and return values from ETAS INCA to a GUI developed in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have a GUI, developed in Python, which require some folder names from INCA.Currently I am able to Open INCA when clicked on a browse button.

My requirement is to get the Folder name, which I click in INCA and display that into my GUI. Is that possible to do? From INCA document, got to know that 'GetName' Method can be used to get the Folder names. But can I capture the click events and get those into my GUI?
If possible what is the package I can use in python to use the INCA methods?

```
def get_inca_connection():
    shortcut_path = r"C:/Program Files/ETAS/INCA7.3/INCA V7.3.lnk"
    os.startfile(shortcut_path)    
    try:
        objIncaApi = win32com.client.Dispatch("inca.inca")        
        return objIncaApi
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("An error occured while connecting to INCA:", e)
        tk.messagebox.showerror("An error occured while connecting to INCA:", e)
        return None
def open_inca():   
    
    inca_connection = get_inca_connection()
    if inca_connection:
        print("Successfully established connection")
ttk.Button(inca_frame, text="Browse", command=lambda index=i: open_inca()).grid(row=i, column=5, pady=10, padx=10)
```

Now I would like to get the  import package name that i can use here to get the "GetName" and other related methods